# How to speed up translation with transformers?

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

I try to translate a dataframe from English to Persian. I use a pertrained langauge model for this purpose, but it's slow, how can I speed it up?

```
model_size = "base"
model_name = f"persiannlp/mt5-{model_size}-parsinlu-translation_en_fa"
tokenizer = MT5Tokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = MT5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(model_name)



with open(fname, 'w') as tsvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(tsvfile, delimiter='\t')
    #writer.writerow(["prefix", "input_text", "target_text"])    
    writer.writerow(["input_text", "target_text"])    
    for i, row in tqdm(df.iterrows(), total=maxlen): 
        prompt = row["input_text"]
        target = row["target_text"]
        if trans:
            input_ids = tokenizer.encode(prompt, return_tensors="pt")
            res = model.generate(input_ids)
            prompt = tokenizer.batch_decode(res, skip_special_tokens=True)
            input_ids = tokenizer.encode(target, return_tensors="pt")
            res = model.generate(input_ids)
            target = tokenizer.batch_decode(res, skip_special_tokens=True)
        writer.writerow([prompt, target])                

print("saved in ", fname)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reduce the inference time of Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-es-en (translation model) from transformer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65541788/how-to-reduce-the-inference-time-of-helsinki-nlp-opus-mt-es-en-translation-mode)

Comment: @Jindřich thanks, I checked it, it lacked english to Persian model (en-fa). I'm not much familiar with tensorflow, but probably I could convert the dataset to tensorflow format and then call the model on it or similar solutions.

Comment: @Jindřich https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/quicktour.html